# How to set ParentID field on Account record related to contact in a Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger that is firing on before insert on the Contact object.  I am trying to set the parent ID field on the Account record that the Contact is associated with.

I can't seem to access the related account through the contact in Trigger.New.  My trigger calls method in a class which is shown below.

What code is needed to set the parentID field of the Account associated with each possible contact record that gets passed into this method?

```
 public static void setParentAccount(List<Contact> contacts) {

    Set<String> domains = new Set<String>();

    for(Contact record: contacts) {
      if(record.email != null) {
       domains.add(record.email.split('@')[1]);
      }
    }

   Map<String, Id> accountsByDomain = new Map<String, Id>();

   for(Account record: [select account_domain__c from account where account_domain__c = :domains]) {
     accountsByDomain.put(record.account_domain__c, record.Id);
   }
  }

  for(Contact record: contacts) {
    if(record.email != null) {
      // the ID of the parent account I want to set on the related Account of this contact
      Id accountId = accountsByDomain.get(record.email.split('@')[1]);

     //  **** Here I want to set the parentId field on the associated account equal to "accountId"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please see below code snippet to solve your problem and mark it answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the AccountId from **accountsByDomain** map which you want to set on the Contact's Account **ParentId**. Please see below code to achieve this.

Take one list of Account which we will use to update the Contact's Account.

```
List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
for(Contact record: contacts) {
   if(record.email != null) {
      // the ID of the parent account I want to set on the related Account of this contact
      Id accountId = accountsByDomain.get(record.email.split('@')[1]);
      if(record.AccountId != null)
          lstAccount.add(new Account(Id = record.AccountId, ParentId = accountId));
    }
}
update lstAccount;
```